# Custom template of DetailsView of an item

Tags: asp.net

I would like to format the DetailsView of a ASP.NET control. Is there a way to apply a template or to create a template?
Also, I when I click "edit" to edit the item, can I open the item editor on a different page?

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateRows="False" DataKeyNames="TABLEID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" Height="50px" Width="125px">
            <Fields>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="TABLEID" HeaderText="TABLEID" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="TABLEID" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="NAME" HeaderText="NAME" SortExpression="NAME" />
                <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" ShowInsertButton="True" />
            </Fields>
        </asp:DetailsView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can create custom templates by using template fields.
You can try something like this.

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateRows="False" DataKeyNames="TABLEID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" Height="50px" Width="125px">
            <Fields>
              <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Price and Inventory">

             <ItemTemplate>

            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Sample Text"></asp:Label>

            </ItemTemplate>

        </asp:TemplateField>

          </Fields>
        </asp:DetailsView>
```

Refere this for more info 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb288033.aspx

Comment: Sure I can change the title and the boundfields to templatefields. However, can I change the structure of the fields i.e. move TableID to the top etc using a template such as XSLT? Also, can I edit in a special form i.e. a pop-up form?

Comment: You can use a pop up like ajax popup or a jquery thing to pops up when you click the edit link.

Comment: I can edit the "Edit" link text but how would I add a javascript on it and make sure it loads the form on a new control?

Comment: If you can catch the Modechanging event of the controller when you click the edit link. Then you can do what ever the thing to edit those records.(may be by using a popup)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.web.ui.webcontrols.detailsview(v=vs.100).aspx
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/474534/Performing-Insert-Update-and-De
refer these and try..

Comment: If you need to go to a separate page for editing.You can use Sessions or ViewState. And using the mode changing event,you can redirect to another page and edit the data and load the previous page again with updated data.

Answer (score 0):

you cant Do it By Using C#, but you can go ahead with JQuery by declaring css class to the Edit link and By Using JQuery Selectors as Class give target = blank it opens in new window. doing all this stuff you cant edit the Details view because it is not in the same page.

Comment: do you have any examples for this?

Comment: if u open in blank page also it is of no use. you cant edit it beacause Detailsview in one page and its events in other page is impossible.

Comment: I am not sure to set the events in another page. Do you have an example?

Comment: i havent had a code its just my knowledge in my Experience. try your best

Comment: he is asking for next page